# How to use unique ids generated in a php while loop in a jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Can someone help me crack this issue? I have some data generated from my MySQL database with unique id's using a while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo'<tr>
    <td><img src="expand.png" id="$row['id']"></td>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'
      <div id="'.$row['id'].'_Expanded">
        //some data regarding the selected id need to be displayed here
      </div>     
 </td>
</tr>';
}
```

I want the div to be hidden on page load, but when i click the image only a single div related to the id should expand in JQuery.

Can somebody help me to retrieve the individual ids to be used in JQuery. Thanks!

Comment: use jquery within while loop

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing dots to append the first row of the string with the variable?

`<td><img src="expand.png" id=" . $row['id'] . "></td>`

Comment: Why do you need ID's to do this?  It's a very simple traverse. Also note you are not using unique ID as both the image and the div have same ID

Comment: @charlietfi div id has '_Expandend' attached to it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: (i hard coded your mysql fetch loop by foreach an array)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .expandable{
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ // onload
    $('.expandableContainer img').click(function(){
      $('#'+this.id+'_Expanded').toggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
$data = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 1],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 2],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 3],
  ['id' => 4, 'name' => 4],
];
foreach ($data as $row){?>
  <tr class="expandableContainer">
    <td><img src="expand.png" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?>
      <div id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>_Expanded">
        //some data regarding the selected id need to be displayed here
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried using the same but it opens all the divs of class expandable

Comment: weird.. ok so let's use your ids (should be also faster). I adjusted the JS in the answer

Comment: if you want the tree to go down farther, you use the same way?

Comment: Yes using the id makes it independent from the structure. You only have to make sure that `expandableContainer` contains `img` and `#.._Expanded`